# If passive euthanasia is allowed, is suicide by starving also allowed in Islam?

Tags: fiqh

Both have same premise which is not giving our own body what it needs. In passive euthanasia, medicine and treatment. In suicide by starving it is food.

Comment: Suicide by any means is not permissible in Islam. And what is your evidence that passive euthanasia is allowed in Islam??.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem I forget where I read it. Might takes time to find it again

Comment: @ahmadnazeem [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiVlKulzYP1AhUnILcAHSEnCYEQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.iium.edu.my%2Fkom%2Findex.php%2Fimjm%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F952%2F648%2F2451&usg=AOvVaw3kT2Z2dLZ9Y9eOvt7kqkGm)

Comment: I'll stress again, suicide in anyway is NOT permissible. However there is a debate regarding a person who is clinically brain dead, someone who is on a life support system. If you can edit your question and provide your evidence it would be easier for the community to provide you with a more viable answer.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiVlKulzYP1AhUnILcAHSEnCYEQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.iium.edu.my%2Fkom%2Findex.php%2Fimjm%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F952%2F648%2F2451&usg=AOvVaw3kT2Z2dLZ9Y9eOvt7kqkGm) Fatwas of: Yusuf Qaradawi, Abd al Azeez ibn Abdullah ibn Bas, Shaykh abd al Razzaq Afif, IMANA (Islamic Medical Association of North Americ), OIC (Organization of Islamic Conference, The fatwa was issued at its 10th session on the 24/2/1408 AH in Amman, Jordan)

Comment: @ahmadnazeem They are talking about active euthanasia

Comment: also, did you read the journal I sent?

Comment: In the fatwah you shared by IIUM it's clearly said in the conclusion that "it's not permissible to discontinue food and hydration", isn't that enough??

Comment: @ahmadnazeem that's why I asked this question. Why do we allow not giving body medicine and treatment while we don't allow not giving food and water to our body. I can't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

no,

Allah says: And do not kill yourselves (nor kill one another). Surely, Allâh is Most Merciful to you (quran 4:29)

this indicates suicide is not allowed. Similarly, killing yourself by rejecting food is not allowed. you must feed yourself, and family members cannot starve their relatives. they are responsible for ensuring they get food and drink.

As for declining medicine or treatment - if is basic medication, the individual is required to take it. if it is treatment that is unlikely to be successful or has a low success rate like many cancer treatments, the patient can choose not to go through it and allow nature to take its course. they would not then be sinful.

Comment: What about the medicine and treatment that impossible to cure the disease, but can prolong my life? Like if I take the treatment or medicine, I can live for 40 years (estimated). But If I don't, I will only live for 2 years. Is that count as basic medicine that I can deny?

Comment: It's allowed to refuse medical treatment and wait for natural death.

Comment: @Jeschu i still lost, but thank you.